# Why would I get an infinite loop with this Adapter Interface Pattern

Tags: go, adapter, mux

I need to replace an existing API interface with one that considers an incoming Auth token and also issues a machine-to-machine token for the outgoing service calls.

In summary, this is an API using gorilla/mux routing framework and I'm just adding endpoints to a mux.NewRouter(). Nothing fancy...yet ;).

I have been trying a few different patterns, but the one that seems most appealing is the Adapter Interface derived by Mat Ryer in https://medium.com/@matryer/writing-middleware-in-golang-and-how-go-makes-it-so-much-fun-4375c1246e81 and https://go-talks.appspot.com/github.com/matryer/golanguk/building-apis.slide#30

In summary with no direct logic, I have done the following and get stuck in an infinite loop when I run the endpoint from Postman.

> {"level":"info","msg":"New Relic Checkpoint!!!
>   /endpoint","time":"2019-08-19T14:28:27-05:00"}
>   {"level":"info","msg":"Security Checkpoint!!!
>   /endpoint","time":"2019-08-19T14:28:27-05:00"}
>   {"level":"info","msg":"Header Checkpoint!!!
>   /endpoint","time":"2019-08-19T14:28:27-05:00"}
>   {"level":"info","msg":"New Relic Checkpoint!!!
>   /endpoint","time":"2019-08-19T14:28:27-05:00"}
>   {"level":"info","msg":"Security Checkpoint!!!
>   /endpoint","time":"2019-08-19T14:28:27-05:00"}
>   {"level":"info","msg":"Header Checkpoint!!!
>   /endpoint","time":"2019-08-19T14:28:27-05:00"}

```
r.Handle(endpoint.Path(), Adapt(r, NewRelicAdapter(endpoint), SecurityAdapter(endpoint), WithHeader(endpoint)))
```

the Adapter Interface is established as follows...

```
type Adapter func(http.Handler) http.Handler

func Adapt(h http.Handler, adapters ...Adapter) http.Handler {
    for _, adapter := range reverseAdapters(adapters) {
        h = adapter(h)
    }
    return h
}

func NewRelicAdapter(endpoint rest.Endpoint) Adapter {
    return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            logrus.Infof("New Relic Checkpoint!!! %v", endpoint.Path())
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
}

func SecurityAdapter(endpoint rest.Endpoint) Adapter {
    return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            logrus.Infof("Security Checkpoint!!! %v", endpoint.Path())
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
}

func WithHeader(endpoint rest.Endpoint) Adapter {
    return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            logrus.Infof("Header Checkpoint!!! %v", endpoint.Path())
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
}

func reverseAdapters(adapters []Adapter) []Adapter {
    for i := 0; i < len(adapters)/2; i++ {
        j := len(adapters) - i - 1
        adapters[i], adapters[j] = adapters[j], adapters[i]
    }
    return adapters
}
```

I would really appreciate knowing why this loops before I get into the details on what each adapter would be doing.

Comment: Where are you seeing a loop? What output do you see, and how do you produce it?

Comment: when I call the /endpoint from Postman...see the logs above...they just keep going and going --- updated description with a simple mux dependency

Comment: Because you're passing `r`, the router, to the adapter, and then you pass the adapter to the router. Why?

Comment: @mkopriva --- see 'answer' below --- same question

Comment: @beauXjames none of them pass the router to adapter and then the result back to router. They might pass the router to the adapter and then the result to `http.Handle`... but they don't recommend to create an infinite loop, and if they do then they are simply wrong as you already know. Most of them pass in a handler, `myHandler`, `indexHandler`... Where are your handlers?

Comment: Good question...I have inherited a legacy environment. The moment you asked this my eyes lit up, as the handler is available from the endpoint.GetHandler() method. The problem is this func does return w,r but it does not Serve the route currently. It creates and interfaces with another magic black box...graphQL. Taking another deep breath.

Comment: for example: https://go-talks.appspot.com/github.com/matryer/golanguk/building-apis.slide#32 `http.Handle -> Adapt -> router -> Adapt -> myHandler`... and [here](https://medium.com/@matryer/writing-middleware-in-golang-and-how-go-makes-it-so-much-fun-4375c1246e81) there's no router at all `http.Handle("/", Adapt(indexHandler, AddHeader("Server", "Mine"), CheckAuth(providers), CopyMgoSession(db), Notify(logger))`

Comment: I think I've got so many different citizens needing attention here and I'm just in the mix. Just talking about this has exposed lots of pieces to the puzzle...stepping away for a sec...thanks for checking it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is because your chain of handlers ends with r, in effect becoming:

```
r.Handle(path, r)
```

You have to have an actual handler somewhere to handle the call, so your setup should look like:

```
r.Handle(path, Adapt(theHandler, adapter1, adapter2, adapter3))
```

However, since you said you're using gorilla/mux, there is another way you can to this. Take a look at Router.Use

https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.Use

Comment: It is suggested in the referenced materials that I pass in the router before the string of adapters. When I just remove it the expectation of the Adapt(h http.Handler, adapters ...Adapter) {} complains and I don't know what to do next.

Comment: I updated the answer.  Let me know if that doesn't help.